# Communicating between two chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to communicate between two chrome extensions, but unable to do so.

Any help would be great in resolving this issue.

1st extension sending msg in background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(
function(tab)
{
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port)
{
     port.postMessage({status:"hello"});
});
```

2nd extension receiving msg in background.js:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "lkddmaimhocofkfhngkdhdicmldnfdpn"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender)
{
  alert('listened bg');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are confused with the sending part and receiving part.

Also, there are some differences between [onConnect](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onConnect)

> which fires when a connection is made from either an extension process or a content script,

and [onConnectExternal](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onConnectExternal)

> which fires when a connection is made from another extension.

Take a look at [Message External](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) and you can use the following sample code to communicate between two extensions.

1st extension sending msg in background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    var port = chrome.runtime.connect("lkddmaimhocofkfhngkdhdicmldnfdpn");
    port.postMessage(...);
});
```

2nd extension receiving msg in background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        // Handle your msg
    });
});
```

Comment: One needs to highlight that the main problem is using `onConnect` instead of `onConnectExternal`. The rest of the logic is flawed, yes, but that's a show-stopper.